# What program is triggered/run when the PrintScreen button is pressed?

Tags: windows, screenshot

What program is triggered to take a shot of the screen when the PrintScreen button is pressed on Windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is set to whatever screen capture program you have set as the default.

For example, I use greenshot at work, so when I press PrintScreen that application is used by default.

So the answer is, it depends but by default. Windows has it's own screen capture tool which is saved to a clipboard ready to be copied and pasted into an graphics utilities application. (eg. MS Paint, Photoshop, Corel Painter etc..).

Comment: Where can I find the default capture tool on Windows? (name of the application?)

Comment: @user1508893: There is no separate app; Windows handles this by itself.